# 301 redirects to all except robots.txt

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

We have moved our website to a new domain and want all pages of the old site to get removed from search engines. It's the same site, same content, just a new domain, so search engines are taking time because of duplicate content (maybe). We have added .htaccess 301 from our old site to new site as:

```
redirect 301 / http://new-domain.com/
```

Now, to remove our old site from search engines, we changed our robots.txt on the old site as:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

The problem is, the search engines are fetching robots.txt from the new-domain.com because of .htaccess 301 redirect.

How do I restrict 301 redirect for robots.txt?

Answer (score 7):

Remove the `Redirect` directive and try this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^robots\.txt$ http://other.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any request except `/robots.txt`.

Answer (score -3):

I was trying different configurations and spent hours and finally I found this code which is working well and hope to get the desired results
Here is the code for disallowing search engines.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Not an informative answer. This approach was mentioned in the question as NOT WORKING to solve this particular problem.